# Sending multiple base64 email attachments using ncat/netcat/telnet

Tags: bash, email, telnet, netcat

I am looking for a solution using `bash` and `ncat`. Working off of [this question on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/38919/send-an-email-with-an-attached-file-using-telnet-or-netcat/), I've reworked it, [mostly this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/539903/77231), very basically; allowing a CC recipient to be included, using `ncat` instead of `netcat`, and cleaning it up for my use (simple stuff). As seen here:

```
# Email Recipient
TOEMAIL="$REPORTRCPT";
# Default Subject
SUBJECT="Build report for $MACHINEFQDN - $DATE @ $DATETIME (PST)";
# Default Contents
MSGBODY="See attachment. Includes all output as seen while running the script.";
# Default Attachment
ATTACHMENT="/tmp/$MACHINENAME-build-$DATE.html"
ATTACHMENT2="/tmp/40_custom-$MACHINENAME-$DATE"
# Default smtp server
mailserver="111.111.111.112"
mailserverPort="25"

fappend() {
    echo "$2">>$1;
}

domain=`grep search /etc/resolv.conf | awk '{print $2;}'`
computer=`hostname`
user=`whoami`
FREMAIL="$user@$computer.$domain"

MIMETYPE=`file --mime-type -b $ATTACHMENT`
MIMETYPE2=`file --mime-type -b $ATTACHMENT2`
TMP="/tmp/tmpmail_"`date +%N`;
BOUNDARY=`date +%s|md5sum|awk '{print $1;}'`
FILENAME=`basename $ATTACHMENT`
FILENAME2=`basename $ATTACHMENT2`

DATA=`cat $ATTACHMENT|base64`
DATA2=`cat $ATTACHMENT2|base64`

rm $TMP 2> /dev/null

fappend $TMP "EHLO $computer.$domain"
fappend $TMP "MAIL FROM:<$FREMAIL>"
fappend $TMP "RCPT TO:<$TOEMAIL>"
fappend $TMP "RCPT TO:<$REPORTRCPTCC>"
fappend $TMP "DATA"
fappend $TMP "From: $FREMAIL"
fappend $TMP "To: $TOEMAIL"
fappend $TMP "Cc: $REPORTRCPTCC"
fappend $TMP "Reply-To: $FREMAIL"
fappend $TMP "Subject: $SUBJECT"
fappend $TMP "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$BOUNDARY\""
fappend $TMP ""
fappend $TMP "This is a MIME formatted message.  If you see this text it means that your"
fappend $TMP "email software does not support MIME formatted messages."
fappend $TMP ""
fappend $TMP "--$BOUNDARY"
fappend $TMP "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8; format=flowed"
fappend $TMP "Content-Disposition: inline"
fappend $TMP ""
fappend $TMP "$MSGBODY"
fappend $TMP ""
fappend $TMP ""
fappend $TMP "--$BOUNDARY"
fappend $TMP "Content-Type: $MIMETYPE; name=\"$FILENAME\""
fappend $TMP "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64"
fappend $TMP "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$FILENAME\";"
fappend $TMP ""
fappend $TMP "$DATA"
fappend $TMP ""
fappend $TMP ""
fappend $TMP "--$BOUNDARY--"
fappend $TMP ""
fappend $TMP "."
fappend $TMP "quit"

ncat $mailserver $mailserverPort < $TMP >> $TMP
rc="$?"
if [ "$rc" -ne "0" ]; then
    echo "Returncode: $rc"
    echo "Please inspect $TMP"
else
    echosuccess "Email successfully sent, you should receive it!"
    rm $TMP;
fi
```

But what I've been continually trying to finagle in to it is multiple `base64` attachments. I've tried a variety of placements of things, `BOUNDARY` etcetera, adding additional variables as you can see above. But I'm coming up empty. Anyone familiar and able to lend a hand? I was hoping it would have been as easy and straight forward as adding the CC recipient.

Answer (score 0):

In principle, your script worked for me (after some adjustments like replacing `ncat` with `telnet`). You should follow its advice and "Please inspect $TMP". But you shouldn't append the diagnostic output to the input with `< $TMP >> $TMP`; better use a separate log output file. Also, the approach

```
DATA=`cat $ATTACHMENT|base64`
```

only works as long as the encoded attachment is not too long for a command line. You could replace the

```
fappend $TMP "$DATA"
```

with

```
base64 $ATTACHMENT >>$TMP
```

to overcome this threshold.